# My ad-sense account disabled because of this react native code?

Tags: javascript, react-native, admob, react-native-firebase

My adsense account is disabled but i didn't receive an email from adsense or admob yet. I think it was disabled because of this code.. I have two admob ads in my app. BannerAd and interstitial . Banner Ad is in bottom of the app. interstitial ad opens when user click add button and I used this code to re generate the ad request.  Can someone tell me this is because their problem or this code problem..

this is my app - [myapp](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wpstickerlksl)

```
//On top of the code

import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

const advert = firebase.admob().rewarded('my-id');
const Banner = firebase.admob.Banner;
const AdRequest = firebase.admob.AdRequest;
const request = new AdRequest();
const request2 = new AdRequest();

request.addKeyword('foobar');
request2.addKeyword('foo').addKeyword('bar');

advert.loadAd(request2.build());


...


//Add button to add stickers and load the interstitial ad after clicking a button.

    addSticker(val1,val2){
    ...
                     setTimeout(() => {
                              if (advert.isLoaded()) {

                                advert.show();
                                advert.on('onAdClosed', () => {
                                        advert.loadAd(request2.build());
                                    });

                              } else {
                                // skip...
                              }

                            }, 1500)

    }
```

Comment: Please refer to links on google for the information about why your adsense account was disabled https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/57153?hl=en and you can also contact their help center, also, I'm not sure but you are opening another ad as soon as one closes. This might create unusual traffic and google takes this type of traffic very seriously

Answer (score 0):

since you are loading add as soon as it is closing .
maybe that will be a problem but in majority of cases if something volatilises the admob terms and condition then they will mail you and stop showing add on that appId .

But it will be good if you go by rule.otherwise your admob account will be blocked.